# Geotools Getcapabilities timeout

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I'm using geotools to get all layers from a Geoserver.

```
    WMSCapabilities caps = null;
    try {
        WebMapServer wms = new WebMapServer( sourceServer, 1000000 );
        caps = wms.getCapabilities();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

All is fine, the code is working well when the capabilities XML is of an average size. The problem is when the XML is huge. I'm trying to play with the `time` parameter of `new WebMapServer()`but still getting the timeout error even with a big timeout value.

```
Failed to execute request http://10.5.115.22/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: How long does it take using curl or wget?

Comment: Well, I've tried using the browser  and it toke about 20, 25 seconds to download the XML.

Comment: But from the command line can show up proxy issues

Comment: Hum... you're right. My proxy is tring to download all the file before send it to the application. I'll try some alternatives and post results here. Thanks.